# Change UITableView background image to be blurred

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, user-interface

How can I change my table view style to be blurred like this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Custom Class like FXBlurView, add a FXBlurView in each cell, and add cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor.

It should work, but it's heavy for the CPU.